# Inverting a list of numbers and skip others

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a list and a number k, invert first k elements and leave next k elements. Repeat this throughout the list. By inverting I mean, changing the sign of the number.

This was an Interview question at Amazon, that I cam across on a website, and I was trying to approach it just by thinking on how to solve it, sure I would also like to know the fastest algorithm for solving it and your ideas.

I thought about partitioning the array into the K-Steps, then invert, skip. Then merge the arrays like in merge sorting.

Comment: change the sign of the number

Comment: @iccthedral what other approaches to solve it :) ? in better complexity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i+=k*2)
    for (int j=0;j<k&&i+j<size;j++)
         arr[i+j]=-arr[i+j];
```

if you are sure that array size is multiple of 2 * k or equal to x * 2 * k - k, then:

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i+=k*2)
    for (int j=0;j<k;j++)
         arr[i+j]=-arr[i+j];
```

Comment: Do think that there is simpler than this?

Comment: Why multiplication rather than unary negation?

Comment: I have verified this solution and it works.

Comment: This is a brute force solution, I would like to get a better complexity.

Comment: There isn't! Want a proof?

Comment: @pjs This won't be slower and I believe that `*=-1` is even more easy to read.

Comment: I change it upon request.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh can you tell us the current complexity of this algorithm? You won't do better than that.

Comment: You are wrong @AhmedSaleh.

Comment: @hasan and AhmedSaleh, I have posted an explanation as a solution (for a matter of space).

Comment: yes complexity is O(n/2) or O(n)

Answer (score 2):

**Complexity of hasan's solution:**

Because you said you think that hasan's solution is O(N^2), I'd like to explain why you are wrong. So, he has suggested:

```
for (int i=0; i < size; i+=k*2)
    for (int j=0; j < k && i+j < size; j++)
         arr[i+j] = -arr[i+j];
```

The number of iterations for the first loop is `size / (k * 2)` and the number of iterations for the second loop is `k`. Hense, the total number of iterations is `size / 2`. Which is also the number of elements in the array that should be modified. You can't do better than that.

Comment: You can do better than that. The complexity is O(1) on a quantum computer.

Comment: I assumed a Von Neumann machine or similar :). You can also do better with a FPGA and a fixed size.